# Too many levels of symbolic links issue

Tags: directory, symlink

Whenever I attempt to `cd` my `Downloads` folder to run a C# program that I have written, I keep getting this message. When I try moving the file to snap and/or socket (the only two which are responding to the `cd` command), it does not appear there. How do I fix the issue with "too many levels of symbolic links"?

[image]

```bash
root@LAPTOP-040SRHIO:~# cd Downloads
-bash: cd: Downloads: Too many levels of symbolic links
root@LAPTOP-040SRHIO:~# ls
Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public snap socket Templates Videos
root@LAPTOP-040SRHIO:~# cd Downloads
-bash: cd: Downloads: Too many levels of symbolic links
root@LAPTOP-040SRHIO:~#
```

Comment: `ls -l Downloads` might help show what is going on

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: @cas, very true, though here the colours give us an additional clue that all symlinks are broken, not just `Downloads`.

Comment: Don't login as `root`, the `root` account is only to perform privilege administrative tasks. The root user having things like personal Downloads, Music, Videos directory is an aberration.

Answer (score 1):

`Downloads` is probably a symlink to itself.  Or to another symlink that points back to Downloads, or a longer chain of symlinks that also results in an effectively infinite chain of symlinks pointing to each other.
e.g.

```
$ ln -s Downloads Downloads
$ ls -lF Downloads 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cas cas 9 Sep 10 13:10 Downloads -> Downloads
$ cd Downloads 
-bash: cd: Downloads: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

The solution is "**Don't do that**".   Either delete the Downloads symlink or re-create it to point to somewhere that exists.